# Split one multi-page docx file into multiple single-page docx files

Tags: linux, ms-word, docx

I would like to do it in the command line (Linux), so that I can automate it without the need to have a user interface in the middle.

Comment: You can try to separate the content of the document by taking one page each time, and then create a file and save it for each.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to extract the content (including formatting) from command line?

Comment: No, I thought you use `Interop.Word`.

Comment: I  think pagination is not inside the XML, every open xml reader decides by itself when to go to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit page layout model in the WordprocessingML.

If the file was last saved by Word however, you should find w:lastRenderedPagebreak elements which you can use.

Alternatively, since you are on Linux, try automating OpenOffice/LibreOffice?